# Magento's other themes do not have permission to skin/

Tags: magento

I have Magento site. Its main theme works normal, but other themes from other domain do not have permission to skin/ folder, skin folder already has read (chmod 755) permission from OS. Does anybody have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

did you set permissions recursively?

```
sudo chmod -R 755 skin/
```

Comment: Yes, main theme has permission to skin, but other themes do not

Comment: How are you adding files from skin folder in local.xml?